# Itemize error while using new environment

Tags: environments, itemize

I have created the counter `ejer`.

```
\newcounter{ejer}[section]
```

Then I have defined a new `exer` environment.

```
\newenvironment{exer}                             
{\refstepcounter{ejer} \noindent
\textbf{Exercise \thesection.\theejer.}\slshape}
{\newline}
```

I want to use it with a `itemize` environment as follows.

```
\begin{exer}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item A1
        \item A2
        \item A3
    \end{itemize}
\end{exer}
```

But it gives me this error.

*! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.*

*l.35 \end{exer}*

What have I done wrong?

Comment: remove `\newline` which should very rarely be used. You may want `\par` instead.

Comment: Thanks! Now it works. But I don't know why. I have used the `exer` environment without `itemize` and it works. Can you explain what has changed?

Comment: You can only use `\newline` or `\\ ` if you are in a line `aaa\newline bbb` is allowed but `aaaa <blank line> \newline bbb` is an error as is `\end{itemize}\newline` So your definition would not give an error (but would give wrong output) if there was just text, and no blank line or list before `\end`

Comment: Thanks! :D How can I mark your answer as right to close the question?